# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is not working on the Server when I'm trying to import a csv file

Tags: php, csv, load-data-infile, mariadb-10.3

I have a csv file and I'm trying to import it to a table on Mysql database. the thing is my code is working on the Localhost, but not on the server.

the code is long, but here is the code where it's showing empty array:

```
if(file_exists("customers.csv")){

 $stmt_Import= $con->prepare("
     CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_users_table ( 
    `Customer_CID_temp` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `Password_temp` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `LastName_temp` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `FirstName_temp` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `Email_temp` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  );
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'customers.csv' 
  INTO TABLE temp_users_table  
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
      (
        `Customer_CID_temp`,
        `Password_temp`,
         LastName_temp,
         FirstName_temp,
         Email_temp
       );
      ");
$stmt_Import->execute();
$stmt_Import->closeCursor();

if($stmt_Import){

      $stmt_select = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM temp_users_table");
      $stmt_select->execute(array());
      $rows = $stmt_select->fetchAll();
      print_r($rows);
   }
 }
```

on the localhost, it prints the array with all the records from the csv file just like i want.
But on the server it prints an empty array

Comment: Error messages? Not working is not a very helpful description

Comment: What version of MySQL is on the Server

Comment: Try using the full path to the file instead of just the file name, so it can find the file easier. Also check for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to find out why it fails.

Comment: no error message, as i said it's working fine on the localhost, but on the server when
I print_r the array and it's empty, means the problem seems to be on the server and its relationship with the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ( I'm not good with servers tho)

Comment: mysql version is : 10.3.29-MariaDB-cll-lve

Comment: And you are using the same version of mariaDB in your local environment?

Comment: @aynber tried using the full path, nothing

Comment: @RiggsFolly 
on my localhost the version is : 10.4.19-MariaDB

Comment: Run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';` via `phpMyAdmin` on both local and server, see if there is a difference

Comment: Different versions on LIVE and DEV is never a good idea

Comment: @RiggsFolly I ran SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile'; 
it's ON on the Localhost and OFF on the SERVER !! 
any idea how to enable it?

Comment: So there is you issue. If thats OFF the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is not allowed

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you so much for your help. I'll contact the server manager since i don't have SUPER Privileges to enable it myself